# Manipulating a serialized field in a database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

Using the Entity Framework is it possible to deserialize a column from a database and re-serialize it upon saving back to the database?

Essentially I have XML that is serialized into a byte array in a database. I want to create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model and I am wondering if somehow I can have this field deserialized in the the data model into a string and then re-serialized after my changes have been made and before it saves it back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are storing the property as `varbinary` in the database. You could have a `byte[]` property that matches the blob column in your class, and expose a property or method to fetch the deserialized `X(ML)Document` object out of the `byte` array. Similarly, having a property setter or method to update the `byte[]` property will allow updating the document in the database.

Example, for reference only, does not include error handling, etc.

```
class MyData
{
     public byte[] XmlData { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     public XmlDocument XmlDocument 
     {
         get
         {
             var doc = new XmlDocument();
             var ms = new MemoryStream(this.XmlData);
             doc.Load(ms);
             return doc;
         }
         set 
         {
             this.XmlData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value.OuterXml)
         }
     } 

}
```

Comment: The datatype of the column in sql server is image. When I create the EntityModel, EntityFramework by default, sets the Type to Binary in the edmx.

Comment: So after the edmx is created, I can right click on the properties heading and hover over Add New and I get these options: Scalar, Navigation, or  Complex Property. Would I choose one of these or are you suggesting I go to the Solution Explorer and expand the edmx file and add a new property somewhere in the .tt or .cs file?

Comment: The generated classes should be Partial - so you should be able to add another Partial definition, and add to the same class.